# How to get the user's phone number after capturing the PayPal payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I have this simple code to process payments using [PayPal Node.js SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk):

```js
// Capture order to complete payment
const PaypalClient = client()
const r = new paypal.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(order_id)
r.requestBody({
  payment_source: { token: { id: order_id, type: 'BILLING_AGREEMENT' } },
})
response = await PaypalClient.execute(r)
```

And... it works great!

The only issue is - **the phone number of the user is missing from the response**.

So, after searching, I found out I need to activate "Contact telephone number" in my [PayPal preferences](https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website). So I activated it. Did not help.

[image: Screenshot]

Then, After some more research, I found a `GET` endpoint to get some details of an order: `/v2/checkout/orders/{id}` ([Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get) for the docs). And it worked!

[image: Screenshot]

But... only sometimes:

[image: Screenshot]

In both cases the "user" (me) entered a phone number (it is required) and the capturing of the payment was successful, but only in some cases the phone number shows up in the response.

## Does anyone know why this happens? Or any other way to get the phone number after the user pays?

...

I also tried calling for different endpoints, such as `/v2/payments/captures/{capture_id}` ([Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get) for the docs) but even there the phone number was not included in the response.

[image: Screenshot]

To clarify: all of my testings were for paying via credit card, and not with a PayPal account. This option exists in the `iframe` of course, and it is a valid payment method that works! Just... the phone number...

**EDIT:**

I discovered that after a few hours (About 6 hours) the phone number does appear in the response:

[image: Screenshot]

But I need to find a way to get the phone number right after the payment is completed!

Comment: is this [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ? (and, also, what is the problem (seeing your last edit)?)

Comment: @Luuk yes, it is on-topic. 
The problem is that I cannot find a way to get the user's phone number immediately after the capturing of the payment.